# Wildcard for hash element in Perl

Tags: perl, hash, wildcard

I am trying to check if a certain hash element exists. I have two keys for the hash:

```
if (exists $hash{$key1}{*})
{
then do blabla
}
```

So, where the * is, I would like to use a wildcard (i.e., that value can be anything). What is/are the wildcard charachter(s) for Perl in a situation like this? Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no wild card characters.

You can get a list of the keys like so:

```
my @keys_in_hash = keys %{ $hash{key1} };
```

…which you can then check to see if it has a length, test using `grep` or whatever.

Comment: You should mention that `keys $hash{key1}` only works for Perl >= 5.14.

Comment: For earlier versions you'd need `keys %{$hash{key1}}`.

Comment: Actually, it should be: `my @keys_in_hash = keys %{ $hash{ $key1 } };`

Comment: See my answer (it's much better)

Answer (score 4):

Your original code

```
if (exists $hash{$key1}{*})
{
then do blabla
}
```

If you want to check if the second level hash contains *any* keys, then you can do this

```
if (%{$hash{$key1}}) {
    # do blabla
}
```

If you want to pick up all keys which match a pattern, say all keys that begin "foo", then you could do this:

```
my @matching_keys = grep m/^foo/so => keys %{$hash{$key1}};

if (@matching_keys) {
    # do something
    # matching values are in @{$hash{$key1}}{@matching_keys}
}
```